# Center fotorama slider on a webpage

Tags: fotorama

I'm using the beautiful and excellent Fotorama slider, but I have a question!

By default, the slider is on the top on the left!

I just want it center on the page.

I find in the .css, but i don't find the answer.

Can u help me?

Answer (score 12):

Add this to your CSS and you should be fine ;-)

```
.fotorama__wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Man, I've been looking for this for days. This works and should be part in the official documentation.